# Why did father of Clojure say that Scheme's true/false are broken?

Tags: clojure, null, scheme, common-lisp

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPNkH-7PRTk), Rich Hickey introduced Clojure for Lisp programmers.

At time 01:10:42, he talked about nil/false/end-of-sequence/'() among Clojure/Common Lisp/Scheme/Java. He said: "Scheme has true and false, but they are broken."

[image: slide]

I don't understand why he said that and why does he consider it's "broken"?

Comment: This table looks a bit confused. I'd rather not try to 'interpret' it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It strikes me you'd rather see it from the horse's mouth, so here's a choice extract from [a message](https://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/34b9a4f67ebc0953) Rich posted:

> Scheme #t is almost completely
>   meaningless, as Scheme conditionals
>   test for #f/non-#f, not #f/#t. I don't
>   think the value #f has much utility
>   whatsoever, and basing conditionals on
>   it means writing a lot of (if (not
>   (null? x))... where (if x... will do
>   in Clojure/CL, and a substantial
>   reduction in expressive power when
>   dealing with sequences, filters etc.

The links in that message are also worthwhile, though the second one may be a bit poetic.

Comment: Honestly, I am still having question marks in my head. So only give you half the points. Excuse me.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, Rich is really complaining that, in Scheme, nil evaluates to true (instead of false) in conditionals?  That does seem like a poor design to me.

Comment: @Nathan - Indeed, it evaluates to #t. Technically, '() evaluates to #t, as Scheme lacks nil unless you define it.

Answer (score 9):

From the chart you posted I'd assume it's because Scheme unlike all the other languages in the chart uses something other than `nil` or `false` for `end-of-seq`. Since `'()` is `non-#f` it would be a truthy value in a conditional, but acts as a falsy value for end of sequence checks.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. But your point doesn't satisfy my need yet. Why called it broken?

Comment: I guess some people would consider it broken if the same thing can be either truthy or falsy depening on context.

Comment: In my opinion end-of-list and false are two distinct concepts and scheme gets it right by distinguishing those. He should have included javascript in that chart, compared to its 7 false values clojure nearly looks sane.

Comment: `clojure=> (if '() 1 2)` returns 1, so `'()` being a #t-value cannot be the reason for calling it broken. (unless rich considers clojures boolean values to be broken as well)

Comment: @subsub: That's exactly what my last sentence means. Some people could consider it broken that Scheme uses a value that's usually truthy to represent end-of-seq. Clojure doesn't, since `()` (no need to quote in Clojure) is truthy and therefore also not used to represent the end of a sequence. Some people like Jörn disagree and I can see why.

Comment: @Michael-kohl: Ah, I thought you were referring to scheme in that last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

In Scheme any value (apart from #f which is False) can be used as True in a conditional test. More info [here](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/True-and-False.html).

**Update**
Forget this answer, since it's the same for Clojure of course. I don't like this implicit truth for all values that are not false, for example in (println (if 1 "true" "false")). Personally I would consider that broken but Rich is probably thinking of something else.

Comment: So? Can you provide more explanations?

Comment: That is the same with clojure (nil/false) and commen lisp (nil). That cant be the reason, thats the right way to do it (in my opinion).

Comment: About your Update: Why should rich consider this bronken why would he implement it the same way?