# When to use "if" and "when" in Clojure?

Tags: if-statement, clojure

When is one better than the other?
Is one faster than the other or does the only difference is the return of false or nil?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `if` when you have exactly one truthy and one falsy case and you don't need an implicit `do` block. In contrast, `when` should be used when you only have to handle the truthy case and the implicit `do`. There is no difference in speed, it's a matter of using the most idiomatic style.

```
 (if (my-predicate? my-data)
     (do-something my-data)
     (do-something-else my-data))

 (when (my-predicate? my-data)
     (do-something my-data)
     (do-something-additionally my-data))
```

In the `if` case, only `do-something` will be run if `my-predicate?` returns a truthy result, whereas in the `when` case, both `do-something` and `do-something-additionally` are executed.

Comment: What if I only have to handle the true case, and no implicit `do` is needed, which is more conventional to use in this case?

Comment: Use `when`. The `do` part is an additional good reason to prefer `when` over `if`, not a necessary precondition.

Answer (score 11):

Use `if` when you have two different expressions: for `true` clause and for `false` clause.

`when` and `when-not` are useful in two cases:

- when you want to perform one or several (implicit `do` helps here) non-pure operations conditionally;
- when you want to evaluate something when some predicate evaluates to `true` (or `false` in case of `when-not`), and return `nil` in opposite case.

---

> only difference is the return of false or nil

There is no major difference between `false` and `nil`, as the both evaluate to `false` in logical context.

Comment: I've noticed a stylistic difference in use of `when` in Clojure and Common Lisp. In CL, some people consider it bad to use `when` if you care about the return value when the test fails; in that case you should explicitly return `nil` in the last clause of an `if`.  It makes sense that it's common to use `when` in Clojure in the same situation, since most code is purely functional in Clojure: return values are rarely ignored. If Clojure programmers followed the CL convention, `when` would rarely be used in purely functional code. (Occasionally `nil` vs. `false` matters.)

Comment: @Mars, it is interesting, is there real reason for coexistence of `false` and `nil` in Clojure? I can think of no situation when `false` could do something that `nil` couldn't.

Comment: I think the general idea is: `nil` means "there's nothing left in the sequence", while `false` just means false. The fact that `nil` also means false allows testing for the end of a sequence simply.  Also, you can do things like `(get {:a 1 :b nil} :c false)`. More discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830571/why-did-father-of-clojure-say-that-schemes-true-false-are-broken), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045404/why-clojure-idiom-prefer-to-return-nil-instead-of-empty-list-like-scheme), [here](http://www.lispcast.com/nil-punning), and [here](http://clojure.org/lazy).

Comment: Also: Because `nil` means something like "empty sequence" as well as false, `next` and `rest` have meaning when applied to `nil`, but throw exceptions when applied to `false`.  Other interesting uses of `nil` include [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some), which can function like a predicate because it returns nil on failure, but isn't really a predicate (therefore it has no "?" in it's name), and [`keep`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/keep) (see doc page).  However, I don't fully understand why Clojure should have both `nil` and `false`.

Comment: @Mars In CL, the recommendation is basically the same as for Clojure, cf. https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lispguide.xml#Conditional_Expressions and https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/faqs/lang/lisp/part1/faq-doc-4.html. From the latter: _Never use a 2-argument IF or a 3-argument `IF` with a second argument of `NIL` unless you want to emphasize the return value; use `WHEN` and `UNLESS` instead. You will want to emphasize the return value when the IF clause is embedded within a `SETQ`, such as `(SETQ X (IF (EQ Y Z) 2 NIL))`._

Answer (score 0):

Since Clojure is still relatively young I think it's worth looking into the much longer history of Lisp practice for guidance here.

Originally `when` was to be used if you have a side effect (e.g. see [1](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node84.html), [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14204/468) among others). Why? Well it doesn't have an explicit return value in the falsy case implying you don't really care about it, and it also has an implicit `do` block (or `progn` in Lisp parlor) which only makes sense if you have side effects.

Sometime in the 90s or so the focus shifted though and most guides start to suggest to use `when` instead of an `if` with only one branch without regards to side effects (for a summary see [3](https://github.com/metacontent/The-One-True-Lisp-Style-Guide#17-conditional-expressions)). Why? Well, if you have an `if` with only one branch it can leave open the question if you missed to provide the alternative branch or if you even have a misplaced parenthesis. In the best case this can lead to confusion, in the worst case to hidden bugs.

The difference is subtle though, if you rely on the implicit `nil` for `if` in the falsy case maybe you should make it explicit. Otherwise you probably already rely on a side effect of the truthy branch so `when` would be appropriate under both guidances. If your expression is functional `and` should be preferred anyway (e.g. see [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14204/468)), the difference here is that you might get `false` instead of `nil` in the falsy case though. But again: if you rely on getting `nil` why not make it explicit? (In other words: I think linting rules like the example in [4](https://github.com/jonase/kibit#kibit) are misguided.)

Sometimes the rationale for using `when` over `if` is given as: one should use the most specific construct one needs in the particular case (e.g. see [5](https://courses.cs.northwestern.edu/325/readings/luv-slides.pdf)). But that same argument can be turned around: don't use `when` if you don't need the implicit `do` form. So while a good guiding principle in general it can not be really applied here.

So I tend to use `when` only when there is a side effect as otherwise there are usually constructs with less imperative smell available (like `and`). That is not to say that an `if` form should only be used for expressions without side effects, as it might very well be that you need a side effect for both branches.