# Generator pattern code can't return value

Tags: clojure

I want to create a generator to do, 1 2 3 4.

```
(defn getNums []
  (loop [i  4
         r []]
    (when (<= i 0)
      r                ;<--- point A
      (recur (dec i) 
             (conj r i)))))

(getNums)  ;Eval to nil.
```

Nothing get return, why ?

Would the code in point A return result vector r ?

Comment: you need at least `if` instead of `when`. and why not use `(range 1 5)`?

Comment: thanks, I am practising loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948511/when-to-use-if-vs-when-in-clojure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*when*, is a clojure macro defined as:

```
(when test & body)
```

So, in your first example, the body of when would be:

```
  (do
  r                
  (recur (dec i) 
         (conj r i)))
```

The *when* test itself is evaluated to false so the body of the when macro is not executed.
The return value of the function it therefore the return value of when itself is return, which is nil. Ex:

```
  (when (< 2 1)) ; nil
```

By the way, there is a build in function *range* that does the same as your method:

```
(range 1 10)
```

And, in a more generic way, you could use the lazy function *iterate*:

```
(take 10 (iterate inc 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn getNums []
  (loop [i  4
         r []]
    (if (<= i 0)
      r
      (recur (dec i) 
             (cons i r)))))

(getNums)
```