# every? identity in Clojure

Tags: clojure, identity

I don't get why the combination of `every?` and `identity` is giving different results in the following two examples. It seems that it gives the expected answer upon calling it on `true` `false` collections, but not with the numbers and strings:

`(every? identity [1 2 3 4])`=> `true`

`(every? identity [true true false])`=> `false`

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Comment: i was thinking that identity passes the args of the coll every time to `every?` and `every?` checks the truthy value of them, goes through the coll and returns true if all of the args have had the same truthy value as the first one. So `every?` doesn't force `identity` to pass the truthy value of the other arguments as `every?` walks through the coll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense in your latter case that `every?` would return `false` since one of the elements in the tested collection is `false`; i.e.:

```
=> (identity false)
false
```

As `every?` works its way across the vector and encounters the above application, it sees a falsy value, so returns such.

```
=> (doc every?)
-------------------------
clojure.core/every?
([pred coll])
  Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else
  false.
```

Comment: In case of true false arguments i can see the logic, but with the numbers `identity` returns the number itself which is java.lang.Long, not a truthy value. Hence i thought it would be rather equal to `(every? #(= % 1) [1 2 3 4])`. What is confusing for me is that: identity returns the first argument it gets from the coll, passes it as the predicate to `every?` and then every? checks every of the rest arguments against that first argument? `(every? identity [false true true])` returns also `false`, does that mean every? checks the first value passed to it by identity against the others?

Comment: @AmirTeymuri, in Clojure every value is "truthy" except for `false` and `nil`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5830571/2472391.

Comment: @AmirTeymuri — No, `identity` is not applied to just the first element.  `every?` applied the predicate (in this case, `identity`) is applied to *each* element in the collection until either it reaches the end of the collection (in which case `every?` returns `true`) or the predicate (`identity`) returns a "falsey" value (namely, `nil` or `false`), in which case `every?` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the clojure documentation for every?:

> Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else
>   false.

By evaluating (identity) on the false value inside the array you are getting false because the identity of false is false.